# Excel VBA write a SQL query off of data from an excel table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in a worksheet in MS Excel, and I am trying to write a query off table1 and paste the results in another worksheet. (there are other details in the table that make it possible to have 2 rows with the same supplier and product).

```
Table1:
Product     Supplier   
apple       A           
apple       A           
apple       B           
apple       C           
banana      A
```

I want to do a query like this "SELECT Supplier FROM Table1 WHERE Product = 'apple' GROUP BY Supplier". At first I just tried to write the query with the table names and column names but that didn't work. So I tried to use ranges instead of the table names and column names.

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim tblRng As Range
Dim clmRng1 As Range
Dim clmRng2 As Range

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

tblRng = Sheets("sheet1").ListObjects("table1").DataBodyRange
clmRng1 = Sheets("sheet1").ListObjects("table1").ListColumns("Supplier").DataBodyRange
clmRng2 = Sheets("sheet1").ListObjects("table1").ListColumns("Product").DataBodyRange

strSQL = "SELECT " & clmRng1 & " FROM " & tblRng & " WHERE " & clmRng2 & " = 'apple' GROUP BY " & clmRng1
rs.Open strSQL, cn

Debug.Print rs.GetString
```

I am getting an error "Object variable or With block variable not set". My main concern is that I feel like this is a very indirect way to do this and I was wondering if there was an easier way to accomplish this task?

Comment: You're missing `Set` in front of your range objects: `Set tblRng = ...`, `Set clmRng1 = ...`, `Set clmRng2 = ...`... but then `strSQL = "SELECT " & clmRng1 & " FROM " & tblRng & " WHERE " & clmRng2 & " = 'apple' GROUP BY " & clmRng1` is going to be quite problematic.

Comment: Yeah that’s what I was thinking when I wrote that. Any alternative approach come to mind by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim objList As ListObject
'    Dim tblRng As Range
'    Dim clmRng1 As Range
'    Dim clmRng2 As Range
    Dim s As String

    strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    cn.Open strCon

'    tblRng = Sheets("sheet1").ListObjects("table1").DataBodyRange
'    clmRng1 = Sheets("sheet1").ListObjects("table1").ListColumns("Supplier").DataBodyRange
'    clmRng2 = Sheets("sheet1").ListObjects("table1").ListColumns("Product").DataBodyRange
    Set objList = Sheets(1).ListObjects("table1")
    s = objList.Range.Address(0, 0)

    'strSQL = "SELECT " & clmRng1 & " FROM " & tblRng & " WHERE " & clmRng2 & " = 'apple' GROUP BY " & clmRng1
    strSQL = "SELECT supplier FROM [Sheet1$" & s & "]  WHERE  Product = 'apple' GROUP BY supplier "

    rs.Open strSQL, cn
```